# Installing node modules to a node_modules folder shared by several sub-components

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I got a large node.js project with the following structure:

```
Root
 |_node_modules
   .
   .
 |_Component_1
   |_src
     |_file1.js
     .
     .
   |_package.json
 |_Component_2
   |_src
     |_file1.js
     .
     .
   |_package.json
 .
 .
 |_Component_n
   |_src
     |_file1.js
     .
     .
   |_package.json
```

In order to avoid redundancies, All components should install their node modules and require them from the shared node_modules folder directly under root.

How can I configure the components' package.json to install to root/node_modules ?